# Easiest way to get `svncopy --pin-externals`-like behaviour with Git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

Currently my project uses Git submodules in a `detached HEAD` way. In context  of a regular development workflow, it would much more convenient to point submodules to the corresponding remote branches' tips (`git submodule add -b master ...`) so the freshest changes in submodules are taken into account automatically. But when it comes to creating tags, which must remain constant over time, submodule links must be fixed on those specific commits that are used when a tag is being created.

In SVN, this fixation can be achieved just by adding the `--pin-externals` argument to a tag creation command, but it looks like Git has no direct equivalent for it. What is my best bet here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: there's nothing to do here.  All superproject commits always direct everything to detached HEADs.  The `-b`s are not used when committing, nor when `git add`ing, only when `git submodule update --remote`ing, and even then you're still on a detached HEAD, just a different one.

---

In Git, submodules are just separate Git repositories.  A superproject commit *always* records the one specific hash to which each submodule will be forced.  So if you've made a superproject commit with hash `a123456`, for instance, the superproject's `a123456` *already* pins *each* submodule: submodule `sub/A` is fixed forever (for this commit) onto, say, `aaaaaaaa` and submodule `moduleB` is fixed forever (for this commit) onto `bbbbbbb`.  When you go back to commit `a123456` in the superproject and run `git submodule update`, `sub/A` will be detached to `sub/A`'s `aaaaaaaa` and `moduleB` will be detached to `bbbbbbb`.

To un-detach the submodules, you must `cd sub/A; git checkout master` and `cd moduleB; git checkout master`.  You can semi-automate this using `git submodule update --remote`, which uses the recorded branch, but what that actually does is not switch `sub/A` to (its) `master` but rather to find out what `sub/A`'s *remote*'s `origin/master` is, by hash ID, and switch `sub/A` to that commit as a detached HEAD.  So `sub/A` will continue to be in detached HEAD mode.

Using `git add` in the superproject just takes the current `HEAD` (usually detached, but even if not, the actual hash ID as reported by `git rev-parse`) from each submodule and records it in the superproject's index, so that the one hash ID will be in the next superproject commit.  The branch name in the submodule is not really important here.  The only use of those `-b master`s in `git submodule add` is for `git submodule update --remote`, and even then it's not really to make the submodule be on a *branch*, it's just to automatically update the submodule's detached-HEAD.